# festival ubuntu not working text to speech

Tags: 14.04, text-to-speech, asterisk, festival

Can anyone help this out, 
my cli log shows following like this,

ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'

ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver 
returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings

ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name

ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
aplay: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help for how to format your content here. Overall, new contributors would benefit by reading https://askubuntu.com/help.

Comment: Why was my edit reversed?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue as well.  Eventually I gave up on trying to fix it directly and instead created a docker-based tool to convert text to speech using a docker image based on Ubuntu 16.04, the last version of Ubuntu where I'd been able to use Festival.

My repo is here.

https://github.com/kevinvandenbreemen/ttsScripts

It's fairly specific to a certain type of text content I like to convert but you can change that by modifying the stdparse.sh file...

Hope this helps :)